# Mathmatical notation for a term of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, notation

If I have a polynomial $f(x) = ax^n + bx^{n-1} + cx^{n-2} \ldots zx^0$, is there any mathematical notation for one term, such as the $x^3$ term. For example, if I have a polynomial of $f(x) = x^6 + \ldots 2x^3 + 5x^2 \ldots + 9$, and I multiply it by $2 + x$ to get $g(x)$, how do i write:

$$    x^3 \text{ terms of } g(x) = 2\cdot(2x^3) + x\cdot(5x^2)$$

Thank you very much!

(Tried looking on wikipedia)

Comment: No. Define your own notation whenever you need it. Stanley has tried to standardize $\left[m\right]p$ for the coefficient of a monomial $m$ in a polynomial $p$ (so that, for instance, $\left[x^3\right]\left(1+x\right)^6 = \binom{6}{3}$), but this is not very widespread these days.

Comment: I think that's the closest there is to a standard notation. (But I honestly wouldn't use it without definition unless speaking to an audience of people who deal with generating functions all the time.)